# Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable ubuntu12 on openstack

Tags: bash, google-chrome, ubuntu

I'm running a script on my `ubuntu` on openstack (env bash) which is trying to install the latest stable chrome browser:

```
sudo apt-get update     
sudo apt-get -y install openjdk-7-jre google-chrome-stable
```

But I'm getting --> `Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable ubuntu`

I tried the following additions but they didn't help:

```
# trying universe repo
sudo apt-get -y install libgconf2-4 libnss3-1d libxss1
sudo apt-get update

# trying something for openstack
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-cloud-keyring
sudo apt-get update
```

Will be happy to hear more suggestions.

Comment: This question will got more attention if you post this in http://www.askubuntu.com

Comment: Thanks, on futute I will post in askubuntu, anyway I figured a way to fix it by adding sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list"

Comment: I know this is very old, but in case someone is still reading (maybe because I was getting beta) I had to add --allow-unauthenticated to my apt-get

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As written in the comment above, The fix is adding:
`deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main` to the source file:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' >>   /etc/apt/sources.list"
```

Answer (score 27):

For information **chrome is not available on ARM**. That is why nothing worked for me here.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for ARM?

Comment: I had that issue on my M1 MacBook when using Docker and solved it with: `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:18-slim`

Comment: not available 32 bit either

Comment: @saby that's going to run in emulation mode on Apple silicon - not performant at all.

Answer (score 25):

Setup key with:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Setup repository with:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'

sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

(https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome)

Answer (score 4):

As indicated by Raphaël Goisque's answer this may happen due to Chrome not supporting ARM.

I ran into this issue on my Apple Silicon based Mac and had to basically choose between 4 options I could come up with:

- use Chromium
- use Firefox
- use a cloud hosted environment, e.g. have a Docker instance running on a machine with a non-ARM processor and connect to it
- use Emulation

Since I wanted to use puppeteer to render PDFs thus depending on certain codecs, I went with emulation, thus simply having to adapt my first line in the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
```

Keep in mind that this may have implications, such as being slower on a Mac, you can find more information in the [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/). Furthermore, depending on your language/framework, such as .NET, QEMU might not be an option:
https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/7.0/supported-os.md#qemu

Therefore, I am currently still looking for ways to fix it for me, but maybe this is not a limitation for your use.

Answer (score 3):

The existing accepted answer is close but fails to use HTTPS:

Setup key with:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Setup repository with:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'

sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

(https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add key:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A040830F7FAC5991
```

and then you could do:

```
echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
apt-get update && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
```

Without key you are installing unsigned package and because of that you might get problems late.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works, try:

```sh
$ touch /etc/apt/sources.list
```